# Parse a method signature string

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code that takes method signature as a String input and then extract information out of it like - return type, modifiers, method name, param types, param names, exceptions.

There are a lot of ways to write a method signature, and I want my code to be able to deal with all of them. So I am skeptical about writing it myself.

Java understands it, thanks to the java grammar. I found this class SignatureParser in 
sun.reflect.generics.parser (source: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/reflect/generics/parser/SignatureParser.java)

I am stuck and not able to use it, however and need your help. Here is what I've tried so far (It is giving an error right in the beginning)

```
MethodTypeSignature mts = SignatureParser.make().parseMethodSig(method);
```

To figure out what is wrong I tried to break it down. But I cannot figure out anything.

Also, this way of parsing leaves me with method type but not method name. Will I have to write the code manually, or can anybody suggest some library method?

Comment: There is probably some ideas of how to do it in javadoc utilities, they are already parsing code and splitting method parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
package org.springframework.asm;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

/**
 * A Java field or method type. This class can be used to make it easier to manipulate type and
 * method descriptors.
 *
 * @author Eric Bruneton
 * @author Chris Nokleberg
 */
public final class Type
```

I also encountered this problem. I saw that the problem was 7 years ago. I wonder if you have solved this problem. I found that the spring framework has this class that can parse method signatures relatively easily. It seems that it is mainly the function of splitting strings, but it is enough.

Answer (score -3):

First of all your method should be defined under a class in a running jvm.
Then you get the information about the class like this.

```
Class cls = Class.forName("yourclassname");
```

After that you can get the information for the function with this method .

```
Method[] metods = cls.getMethods();
```

You can iterate through the methods find the one you are interested in and use lots of useful functions to extract information like getParameterTypes or getExeptionTypes...

```
Method yourMethod = null;
if (metods[i].getName().equals("yourmethodname")){
    yourMethod = methods[i];
}
yourMethod.getParameterTypes();
yourMethod.getReturnType();
...
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. The code in your explanation works, like you said, for a class in a running JVM. It extracts information from the methods defined in that class.

My problem is that I'm taking the input of method signature from the user (and storing it in a string). So how do I get from there to your solution?

There is a missing link that I cannot figure out...

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from parsing class name and function name from method signature :))

Comment: no no no. What I mean is... Imagine this text area. The user enters "public static void main(String[] args) here. I take it. store it in a `String methodd = new String("public static void main(String[] args)`... Where do I go from here... The solution that you are suggesting parses methods in my class... So for example this is my class:
`public class MethodSpy {
    String methodd;
    public static methoddParser (String methodd) {
        //method body
    }
}`

So your solution will parse this method - `public static methoddParser(String methodd)`

I want to parse the `String methodd`

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't answer the question. @Nikhil has a method signature, and he wants to get the parameter and return types out from it.